# How to represent a "light" bastard sword?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

I want to have a character wield a bastard sword, but I'm trying to find fluff for it.

I want it to be...

- Light, as in that is could be wielded with quick strikes without being overly tiring, and being able to stop without trouble due to momentum.
- Straight, as in not curved, like a katana
- double edged, as in able to strike with both sides of the sword
- sensibly used with both styles, as in making sense to wield in 1 hand, but just as sensible to wield in 2.

Comment: (Accordingly, I have voted to close this as "unclear what you're asking", as I can't tell what problem you need solving, other that maybe just misunderstanding how swords work.)

Comment: I really don't understand what you're getting at here.  Rather than asking for a light bastard sword, could you instead describe the kind of sword you actually want, and maybe we can find someting for you?  It's not at all clear what it is about bastard swords that you do and don't want.

Comment: After the edit, I am still not clear on what problem needs solving: you want fluff that is like your requirements—but how is that not the answer already?

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like what you're looking for is mechanically a bastard sword.  You don't need to have a different kind of sword, mechanically, in order to have a sword like the one you're describing.

I'd suggest watching [this](https://youtu.be/iF_kxAqS_8k?t=1m25s) YouTube video, starting at 1:25.  This video shows someone talking about various kinds of swords from various eras, and makes the point that there is a "continuum" of swords between a longsword and a two-handed sword, and different people might have different ideas about exactly what counts as a bastard sword.

With that said, you could certainly describe a weapon that does 1d10 damage with a 19-20 crit range, but fits more with your idea of the sword you want.  You could describe it as a slightly shorter and more graceful sword than a bastard sword, with a long hilt that allows a two-handed grip and possibly a weighted pommel to help balance the weapon.  There is no real reason that a refluff of the bastard sword mechanics like this wouldn't work.